# How can I hide 3 buttons close, minimize and full size on AppKit SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit

I need some help with figuring out how to disable/hide the close, minimize, and resize buttons in OS X SwiftUI. Here's the code I tried.

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView(container: environment.container)
    }
    #if canImport(AppKit)
    .windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
    #endif
}
```

Thanks for

Answer (score 0):

Get hosting `NSWindow` to control its appearance:

```swift
@State private var window: NSWindow!

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .background {
                if window == nil {
                    Color.clear.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for:
                        NSWindow.didBecomeKeyNotification)) { notification in
                        if let window = notification.object as? NSWindow {
                            window.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
                            window.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
                            window.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Or hide the entire title bar:

```swift
window.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.superview?.isHidden = true
window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
```